# File.read returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, file

I created a file in ruby and saved some hashes in it. When I read the file, I get nil. Here is the code:

```
my_hash = Hash.new
file = File.open("my_file.json", "w")

my_hash["test_key"] = "0.1"
file.write(my_hash.to_json)

file_read = File.read("my_file.json")
p file_read // This prints nil
```

When I open the file, I see `{"test_key":"0.1"}`

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close the file after writing to it, so it's most likely that the Operating system has not flushed the pending IO to file by the time you tried to read from the file.  As far as the OS was concerned, the file did not yet exist.

Comment: Ahaa... That was it. Thanks mcfinnigan!

Answer (score 1):

Close the file after you're done writing:

```
my_hash = Hash.new
file = File.open("my_file.json", "w")

my_hash["test_key"] = "0.1"
file.write(my_hash.to_json)
file.close # close after writing

file_read = File.read("my_file.json")
p file_read
```